# How can i edit the details renders by the sj:head tag in struts

Tags: jquery, eclipse, jquery-ui, struts2, jsp-tags

I am getting following text from the `<sj:head locale="en"/>` tag when i view the page in my browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/struts/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.scriptPath = "/struts/";
      $.struts2_jquery.gridLocal = "en";
        $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

In that i want to change the `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` to `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` how i can i edit this.
I am using eclipse editor to edit this `jsp` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just change the jquery version of the plugin, if you need specifically `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` as your jquery version, you should set your `struts2-jquery-plugin` version to 3.3.0. this version uses `jquery 1.7.1`

[image]